# Calculated Binding in net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

is there an easy way to use a calculated property in a view?

I need to give a left padding proportional to an actual width of a grid, or the width of a column.

For example if I tilt the phone the grid gets wider and I want to update the padding.

This seems to work, but I want to calculate a value from the width, for example width/50:

```
<Label Text="Seg"
       Style="{StaticResource subTitleLightTextStyle}"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Padding="{Binding Source={x:Reference bodyCalendar},
                           Path=Width}"
       Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: use an `IValueConverter`